# How I can store 1 as a Double mongoose, mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As a title, how I can store value 1 as a Double value?

I'm using 'mongoose-double' to support Schema type, but It's not working.

Below is example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);

const Double = mongoose.Schema.Types.Double;

const user = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  value: Double,
});

mongoose.model('User', user);
```

When I save an user with value = 1

```
const user = new User({ name: 'Jack', value: 1 });
```

I see in mongodb, typeof value = int32

When I save an user with value = 1.142

```
const user = new User({ name: 'Jack', value: 1.142 });
```

I sse in mongodb, typeof value = Double

How I can fix it? I want to typeof value is only Double

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you obtain your values from,
you can check your type while obtaining your value and change/cast it to double first, otherwise if it's a string, change your whole numbers into `1.0` instead of `1` before saving it into your database, by using:

```
yourValue.toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Omg ! I tried ```yourValue.toFixed(2)``` but in mongodb, type has been parsed to String.

parseFloar(1.toFixed(2)) => back to int32